# If you have a group $G$ with $|G|={\rm ord}(G)=n$, does that imply that there exists an element $g$ in $G$ such that ${\rm ord}(g)=n$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am new to group theory this semester and have found myself getting confused with regards to the order of elements in groups.

My question is if you have a group $G$ with $|G|={\rm ord}(G)=n$, does that imply that there exists an element $g$ in $G$ such that ${\rm ord}(g)=n$?

I know that this would hold true for cyclic groups by definition, but I am having a hard time understanding if this applies to other kinds of groups as well.

Comment: One of the next theorems coming in group theory is [Cauchy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)). If the order of $G$ is divisible by a prime $p$, then it is true that there exists an element of order $p$. If $p$ is not prime, it is false. This is often mentioned together with the theorem. So have a look at Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for the answer and for showing me the ropes around here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Consider $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$, which has order four. All its nontrivial elements have order two.

Answer (score 2):

No if you take $$G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$ Then you have $|G| = 4$, but for all $g = (a,b)\in G$ we have $g^2 = (a^2,b^2) = (e,e)$. So no elements of your group have order $4$.

Answer (score 2):

Just to move away from the order $4$ (minimal) counterexample, consider $S_3$, of order $6$: all its nontrivial elements have order $2$ or $3$.

Answer (score 2):

Despite all the counterexamples, the statement is true if and only if $G$ is *cyclic* of order $n$. That is $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

What a cute question.

Well,  just to reiterate @NickyHekster, a group is cyclic if and only if it's singly generated.  That's if and only if it can be written $G=\langle g\rangle =\{g^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$.

If $G$ is finite of order $n$, then $G\cong\Bbb Z_n$, and $g$ has order $n$.

So the answer to your question is no.  However,  if $p\mid n$, where $p$ is prime,  then there *is* an element of order $p$ (Cauchy's theorem).

There's one more possibility though:  there's an infinite cyclic group.   And you're surely familiar with it.  It's the integers, denoted $\Bbb Z$.

---

Actually there's a group,  called the circle group,  and I believe denoted $\Bbb T$, which contains all the finite cyclic groups (and lots of copies of $\Bbb Z$) as subgroups.   That's the aforementioned $\Bbb Z_n'$s.  They are also the so-called $n-$th roots of unity. They are evenly spaced around the unit circle.

And apparently that's where the term "cyclic" originates.

---

One more thing.  Cyclic groups are abelian.   So as soon as a group isn't abelian,  it can't be cyclic.